# Generic Cryptic Crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Here's a cryptic crossword. I was originally planning on having some sort of overarching theme, but the words were just not fitting together how I wanted. Good luck!

[image]

**ACROSS**

1. Interpreter from the sea shore (3)
4. Vehicle belongs to head of household (3)
7. I said I'll send you a document of the data (5)
12. A strange, wee animal (3)
13. Those times are left behind (3)
14. I love the portal's sound (5)
15. Flower doesn't know why it's so small (3)
16. Tree parts still brown? Nope, since they changed (4, 5)
18. Chief's son ate some weird rice (4)
20. Wise plant (4)
21. Large man finished a turkey (3)
22. Flourishing after weight lifted from Midwest city (8)
24. A little elf starts to eat (4)
25. Smiling woman utters sad moan (4)
26. Trainee De Vita disconnected, deactivated, and reassembled (5)
27. Trying to imagine differently and endlessly (6)
30. Democrats say the right stove is out of order (6)
31. Afternoon soup containers flipped by king (5)
32. Alone, sounds very sad (4)
33. Men sometimes ignore reliable sources (4)
34. Network in upstairs storage spans ocean (8)
38. Salt Lake Athlete unable to entertain (3)
39. Earth can redirect without core (4)
40. Long story about neon told backwards (3)
41. In the meantime, Charlie confused his English cuisine (9)
44. I'm going to get sick (3)
45. Excited to listen to revolutionary Jamaican music without repeats (5)
46. Era can handle male's absence (3)
47. Luke or Lisa responds digitally (3)
48. Sailboat capsized in the lakes (5)
49. Tom, Dick, and Harry are heartlessly rude (3)
50. Can someone help with my Stack Overflows? (3)

**DOWN**

1. Public figure parties unjudged (5)
2. Spiral gives up a coin for wife (5)
3. I replace fifty welcoming suns (5)
4. Mushroom gives you back muscles (3)
5. The grand raisin is emerging (7)
6. Fruit wants to forbid Annalee (6)
7. Confront the gaps when trouble sounds (4)
8. A dreadful odor creates fuss (3)
9. Reveal the key of the damaged fin (7)
10. Tricky kid can run away, front to back (7)
11. A messy set contained in sets of six lines (7)
17. Hobo's heart shaped like oval (3)
19. Warped cosmic books (6)
23. Religious figure cuts off primate's tail (4)
24. Angry snob at race hands these over (6)
26. Drink tastes like fermented coal (4)
27. Mad masseuse endlessly jumps to conclusions (7)
28. First, the Latin eyes moved (7)
29. Battle between Napoleon and the twisted ogre man. (7)
30. Mad love around playground game has potential. (7)
32. Model gives yell, not about a river (6)
34. Try to flip Mamma's last name (3)
35. Mistakenly, I salt the appendages (5)
36. Sounds like I stick to the house (5)
37. He yells, "everyone is in Computer Science!" (5)
39. Carnivore's backwards head creates tomfoolery (4)
42. Leader creates enormous office (3)
43. Going back, the total creates an order of magnitude (3)

Comment: This is my first time making a crossword or cryptic clues. I greatly appreciate any feedback about the clues' quality and/or ideas on how to incorporate a theme.

Comment: As a side-note on how new this is to me, I didn't even realize while making this that cryptic crosswords have very different grid designs from American crosswords. I apparently made a strange conglomeration of the two very different styles.

Comment: Yeah, I was really confused when I first saw this - cryptic crosswords have less "checked" cells (that is, cells that have two crossing entries), in order to have more words that can be clued with interesting wordplay. (This way, you don't run into the problem of 'crosswordese' or lots of obscure abbreviations.)

Comment: @Deusovi Well if I make another one somewhere down the road, I'll keep this all in mind.

Comment: Hope you do make more! These were much better than most people's first clues - keep Gareth's advice in mind and I'm sure your future cryptics will be great :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the solution:

> [image]

OP requested comments, so here are some.

> Many of these clues are rather "loose": they have words that serve no function in the "grammar" of the crossword clue, but are there only to make the surface reading work out (e.g., "I" in 14a; "adore" means "love" -- it doesn't mean "I love" nor does it mean a person who loves; or "He" in 37d), or have definitions that aren't really definitions (e.g., 31a; I'm not sure whether the definition is meant to be "afternoon" or "afternoon soup" but neither really seems like a definition of "snack" to me), or are missing a wordplay indicator (e.g., 33a, which needs something to say "take the first letters of these words"), etc. So my main bit of feedback would be: cryptic crossword clues have strict rules, and you should be less willing to break them. Having said that, there were some clues I really liked; e.g., 45a is simply a good clue, and I like the idea of 26a although I'm not sure its grammar *quite* works.

Comment: OMG! That was fast!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I did my best to follow the rules strictly, but I guess I forgot a few details. All the answers look correct.